# Using mathmode in '\graph[layered layout]' environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to get into TikZ and pgf to create figures and graphs. In the package there is the `\graph` command, which provides a simple yet power full interface to draw graphs and trees. However I can't seem to get the math mode working with it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\graph[layered layout]{a -- b};
\end{document}
```

works just as intended, producing

[image: compiled output of above code]
However I want to have it display formulas and Greek letters as labels of nodes or edges, such as `\delta` or `x\cdot (1-x)`. Changing above to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\graph[layered layout]{$a$ -- b};
\end{document}
```

or using `$\delta$` or similar will crash on compilation. In particular above code would crash with

```
File ended while scanning use of \tikz@cc@parse@factor.
```

I toyed around with it and tried to make it work, but I can't seem to find the solution. How can I have formulas and Greek letters as names of nodes in my graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node text with math can be given with quotes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\graph[layered layout]{"$\delta a$" -- "$x\cdot(1-x)$"};
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: wow, that was a lot simpler then I expected